# np.append when one of the values could be empty or None

Tags: python, numpy

I have this pseudo code:

```
a = np.zeros([3,3])
b = np.zeros([3,3])
c = np.append(a,b,axis=0)
```

But the problem is, `a` or `b` or both could be None instead of the array that they are. So I have done this:

```
def emptyappend(a,b):
    if type(a)==np.ndarray and b is None:
        return a
    elif type(b)==np.ndarray and a is None:
        return b
    elif type(a)==np.ndarray and type(b)==np.ndarray:
        return np.append(a,b,axis=0)
    else:
        return None
```

This seems really ugly and not very "pythonic", but I can't figure out a simple way to do this... any ideas?

Comment: The pythonic thing is to collect arrays into a list, and join them with concatenate.  `np.append` is misnamed and misused.

Comment: Why is it misnamed? it is for appending by specified axis

Comment: It reminds people of list append too much.  Do `np.source(np.append)` to see its code.

Comment: I looked at it and you're absolutely right, they just `concatenate` anyway... who knew.... tnx for the lesson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the arrays only if the conditions match otherwise return one of the two short-circuiting with `or`:

```
def emptyappend(a, b):
    if type(a) is np.ndarray and type(b) is np.ndarray:
        return np.append(a, b, axis=0)
    return a or b
```

Comment: isn't the first 2 tests not necessary if I do the other 2 tests?

Comment: @OferSadan You're right. The type checks should handle those.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!